# Excel data model slicers, "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I've written a macro which places variable names into a Dictionary (called Occs) and then tries to select those names in a slicer. There seems to be one line I've got wrong:

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim Occs As New Dictionary
Occs.Add "001", "001"
Occs.Add "002", "002"

Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim sI As SlicerItem
Dim index As Integer

Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Occupation_Code1")

sC.ClearManualFilter

For index = 1 To sC.SlicerCacheLevels.Count

    For Each sI In sC.SlicerCacheLevels(index).SlicerItems

        sI.Selected = Occs.Exists(sI.Caption)

    Next sI

Next index

End Sub
```

It says there's a "1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" on the line that should actually select the items, if they're in the Occs Dictionary:

```
sI.Selected = Occs.Exists(sI.Caption)
```

What should this line be instead? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've not worked with slicers before but have you checked the local variables to see if `sI` is `Nothing`?

Comment: It says sI has a Value of [nothing] and a Type of SlicerItem/SlicerItem. Also, it says sC has a Value of [nothing] and Type of SlicerCache/SlicerCache. Is this right? Thanks for the help

Comment: `Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Occupation_Code1")` after this line, `sC` is `Nothing`? That doesn't make sense. Did you step into the `sI.Selected = Occs.Exists(sI.Caption)` line?

Comment: Actually sorry, my mistake - when I step into the Occs.Exists line, it says that sI is SlicerItem/SlicerItem and in the first loop it has various properties, including a Caption of "001" (which is the first item in the slicer). When I step into again, it gives the "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: Okay it seems like the SlicerItems.Selected property is Read-Only for OLAP cubes (i.e. power pivot slicers). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sliceritem.selected?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_SlicerItem_Selected Need to find another way it seems